# Make content (div/images) limit the min-width of containing div

Tags: html, css

I have an container div that has a variable size based on width of the page.  This is where I insert my content, however sometimes I insert iframes or images that look fine when the page is at full width but if the browser is shrunk the content either overflows or is hidden.  The latter is what I might have to do but is there anyway to tell the container div to not become smaller than the width of the contained contents?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/K5RXR/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `min-width:500px;`

More info about [min-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/min-width)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K5RXR/10/ like so?  The problem with this is I cannot apply min-width to the container.  The container will not know what content I am putting in it. I'll typically want it to be at it's set width, unless the content (image in blog post, special page) needs it to be larger.  Unless you are suggesting that I use overflow: hidden; and then add the `<style>#container {min-width: ##px}</style>` to pages that may need it.